# How do I test reprompt message with echosim.io simulator?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am new to Alexa, is there any way to test reprompt text using any simulator like echosim.io

Alexa doesn't reprompt back to me after taking my voice input once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we can test the reprompt feature using echosim.io as the feature relies on the user for input.

But you should be able to see your reprompt text in the lambda response using the simulator in the dev portal or console.